# flutter - Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Widget

Tags: flutter, bloc

I've a flutter app with two page. Page uno with a Stateless Widget that call a CounterCubit provider. Page due with a Stateless Widget that call a Counter2Cubit provider. I call page uno but when i go to page due i get the error Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Due Widget

How can i solve this problem?

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      routes: {
        '/uno' : (context) => const Uno(),
        '/due' : (context) => const Due(),
      },
      home: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers:[
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => CounterCubit()
          ),
          BlocProvider(
            create: (_) => Counter2Cubit()
          ),
        ],
        child: Uno(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Uno extends StatelessWidget {
  const Uno({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
        builder: (context, count) => Center(child: 
          Column(
            children: [
                Text('$count'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //Change Theme
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/due');
                  },
                  child: const Text('Successivo'),
                ),
              ],
          )
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().increment(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().decrement(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

```
class Due extends StatelessWidget {
  const Due({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final bloc = context.read<Counter2Cubit>();

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<Counter2Cubit, int>(
        bloc: bloc,  
        builder: (context, count) => Center(child: 
          Column(
            children: [
                Text('$count'),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    //Change Theme
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Due()));
                  },
                  child: const Text('Precedente'),
                ),
              ],
          )
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => context.read<Counter2Cubit>().increment(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () => context.read<Counter2Cubit>().decrement(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: You instantiated the two cubit in one, to access cubit2 in due, you would need to pass it via blocProvider.value. But what's your goal? Would it be a cubit on each screen? Does the uno screen need to know about the existence of cubit2?

Comment: I want to use countercubit in page uno and counter2cubit in page due. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done this way. So you have the discard of the block, when leaving the screen, but whenever you push a screen, you will have a new instance of the cubit. This would be what I would recommend.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      routes: {
        '/uno' : (context) => const Uno(),
        '/due' : (context) => const Due(),
      },
      home: Uno(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Uno extends StatelessWidget {
  const Uno({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => CounterCubit(),
      child: UnoMain(),
    );
  }
}

class UnoMain extends StatelessWidget {
  const UnoMain({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, int>(
        builder: (context, count) => Center(
            child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('$count'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //Change Theme
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/due');
              },
              child: const Text('Successivo'),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().increment(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () => context.read<CounterCubit>().decrement(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Due extends StatelessWidget {
  const Due({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => Counter2Cubit(),
      child: DueMain(),
    );
  }
}

class DueMain extends StatelessWidget {
  const DueMain({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    final bloc = context.read<Counter2Cubit>();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Material App Bar'),
      ),
      body: BlocBuilder<Counter2Cubit, int>(
        bloc: bloc,
        builder: (context, count) => Center(child:
        Column(
          children: [
            Text('$count'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                //Change Theme
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Due()));
              },
              child: const Text('Precedente'),
            ),
          ],
        )
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => context.read<Counter2Cubit>().increment(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 4),
          FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.remove),
            onPressed: () => context.read<Counter2Cubit>().decrement(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```